# Get current user information in Apigility Resource

Tags: php, zend-framework, oauth-2.0, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I just started with Apigility and oAuth2, and I was wondering if it is possible to get the currently authenticated "loggedin" user when fetching information from a database.

I currently have the following code:

```
/**
 * Fetch all or a subset of resources
 *
 * @param  array $params
 * @return mixed
 */
public function fetchAll($params = array())
{
    var_dump($params);
    // Using Zend\Db's SQL abstraction 
    $sql = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Sql($this->db); 
    //I would like to get the currently logged in user here... but how?
    $select = $sql->select('projects')->where(array('userid' => 1));; 

    // This provides paginated results for the given Select instance 
    $paged  = new \Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbSelect($select, $this->db); 

    // which we then pass to our collection 
    return new ProjectsCollection($paged);  
}
```

I did a lot of searching already but I have no clue how to access the user information or the access token, do I need to parse the request header for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was also looking for it. I didn't found any documentation about that. But the answer is quite simple:

Resource classes inherits `ZF\Rest\AbstractResourceListener` which already has a method `getIdentity`.

```
/**
 * Fetch all or a subset of resources
 *
 * @param  array $params
 * @return mixed
 */
public function fetchAll($params = array())
{
    // if user isn't authenticated return nothing
    if(!$this->getIdentity() instanceof ZF\MvcAuth\Identity\AuthenticatedIdentity) {
        return [];
    }

    // this array returyour query here using $userIdns the authentication info
    // in this case we need the 'user_id' 
    $identityArray= $this->getIdentity()->getAuthenticationIdentity();

    // note, by default user_id is the email (username column in oauth_users table)
    $userId = $identityArray['user_id'];

    // fetch all using $userId
}
```

You can also use `getIdentity` in RPC services.

I'm using the latest version of apigility.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I made it work. I could in the end also get the userid with `$this->getIdentity()->getRoleId()`

Comment: Nice. I didn't notice that!

Answer (score 3):

I found in the end a shorter way to get the userid, just adding it as answer for the sake of completeness.
You can get the `identity` object like @ViníciusFagundes mentioned `$this->getIdentity()` and this identity object has the function `getRoleId()` which returns the identifier of the user.

```
$user_id = $this->getIdentity()->getRoleId();
```